# Can't open a new window with PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qwidget

I made this code .. A new window should open when i fill the requirements and press login but when i do that the window open then it disappears .. i saw a lot of codes using OOP but i don't understand them so i need any one to give me a simple solution

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys
import os
import shutil
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
main_window = QWidget()
main_window.setWindowTitle("Keep It Safe V1.5")
main_window.setWindowIcon(QIcon('lock.png'))
main_window.resize(350, 180)
main_window.move(500, 200)
login_btn = QPushButton('Login', main_window)
login_btn.resize(150, 30)
login_btn.move(100, 120)
User = QLineEdit(main_window)
User.resize(250, 30)
User.move(50, 10)
User.setPlaceholderText('Enter your user name')
password = QLineEdit(main_window)
password.resize(250, 30)
password.move(50, 60)
password.setPlaceholderText('Enter your passsword')
password.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)
check = QCheckBox(main_window, text="I accept the terms and policies")
check.move(50, 95)
def login_check():
    user = User.text()
    Pass = password.text()
    if user == "Admin" and Pass == "admin" and check.isChecked():
        print("Clicked")
        sec_win =QWidget()
        l = QLabel(sec_win , text = "second window opened")
        sec_win.show()
    else:
        fai = QMessageBox.warning(main_window, "Error", "Incorrect user name or passwprd")
login_btn.clicked.connect(login_check)
main_window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A variable that is created within a function is local, so it will be deleted when it is finished executing, and sec_win is so it will be displayed but an instant later it will be removed, the solution is to create it before and only show it when necessary.

```
import sys

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
main_window = QWidget()
main_window.setWindowTitle("Keep It Safe V1.5")
main_window.setWindowIcon(QIcon('lock.png'))
main_window.resize(350, 180)
main_window.move(500, 200)
login_btn = QPushButton('Login', main_window)
login_btn.resize(150, 30)
login_btn.move(100, 120)
User = QLineEdit(main_window)
User.resize(250, 30)
User.move(50, 10)
User.setPlaceholderText('Enter your user name')
password = QLineEdit(main_window)
password.resize(250, 30)
password.move(50, 60)
password.setPlaceholderText('Enter your passsword')
password.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)
check = QCheckBox(main_window, text="I accept the terms and policies")
check.move(50, 95)

sec_win =QWidget()

def login_check():
    user = User.text()
    Pass = password.text()
    if user == "Admin" and Pass == "admin" and check.isChecked():
        print("Clicked")
        l = QLabel(sec_win , text = "second window opened")
        sec_win.show()
    else:
        fai = QMessageBox.warning(main_window, "Error", "Incorrect user name or passwprd")

login_btn.clicked.connect(login_check)
main_window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: But do you know why when i set a background image every widget bg changes too !!